# Is there any way to query code generated in the results?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have generated chunks of code and concatenated it into a single string which is stored in a temporary table. Is there any way to run this string of code without copy-pasting the results in the query?

I have tried using set and exec to read the code, however it only returns the string value stored and does not run the actual code.

In the temporary table ##steg4 I have stored the string of code which I am intending to run. I have tried:

```
declare     @cmd    varchar(max)
begin 
    set @cmd = 'select string from ##steg4'
    exec (@cmd)
end
```

However, it does not read it as code and only as the result text-string. Is there any way to make it so that is reads the string of code stored in ##steg4 and outputs a new result based on that code?

I am hoping that there is a way to read the code without having to do manual work (copy-pasting the generated code stored in ##steg4).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
declare @cmd varchar(max);

selecct @cmd = string
from ##steg4;

exec sp_executesql @cmd;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am not getting your suggestion to work, getting the error message "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 49).

Comment: @Kinzerb Change `set` to `select`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the feedback. I still did not manage to get it working using your suggestions, I instead tweaked the initial code used and got the answer I wanted:

```
declare @cmd varchar(max)
begin 
    set @cmd = (select string from ##steg4)
    exec (@cmd)
end
```

Apparently, the parenthesis was missing from the select-statement.

With kind regards,
Alexander